# Decode/decrypt string | FoxPro 9

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have an old Visual FoxPro 9 application which stores data in dbf files.

There is encrypted/encoded name of the company stored in this format -

```
3:569<9?=<?B?FABEHEGGHOHKQQNUSQXTTWXWYY[Z[`^adbab547:8789;>A>@@ACCDFFGIIJLLMOOPRRSUUVXXY[[\^^_aabd3466799:<<=??@BBCEEFHHIKKLNNOQQRTTUWWXZZ[]]^``acc3556889;;<>>?AABDDEGGHJJKMMNPPQSSTVVW\]Z]b]a^`ddc5;5::
```

How to decode/decrypt it?

Comment: You need to know the encryption used. Ask to developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic or default encryption method for VFP. This means, whoever originally developed the program to store and retrieve the data associated with this table, will have created their own encryption/decryption method or utilized a third-party function. If you have source code that stores and retrieves the data for this table, then you should be able to figure it out.